# Client Side Emailer

Tags: jquery, json, email, smtp

I am building a plugin that is written in jquery and designed to function standalone without the aid of server side code. I know how to write the server side code, I just don't want to support it.

That being said, I need to email images. It seems that sending email (via smtp) with javascript is not possible and using mailto will not permit me to attach or include an image. However, I was hoping there may be a way to send a json post to a public URL that some company had exposed for the purpose of processing emails.

Has anyone ever tried something like this before?

Comment: If you are now considering creating a plugin to rely on a public server that is out of your hands, stop it. You cannot guarantee that the service will be available.

Comment: A public service to send E-Mails? Very, very hardly. Something like that would be overwhelmed with spam within a day.

Comment: @Pekka There are such things as servers that throttle input and even ban connections when they get flooded. The SMS gateways are still around and they are publicly accessible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Comment: @TheZ Thanks for the reminder. Growing frustrated with a problem is no excuse to turn to a bad solution. It will probably be easier to maintain a server than to constantly update a plugin.

Comment: @user1505431 Definitely easier to do it yourself. You just have to do everything you can to gain people's trust that you are not tracking email contents and such. However, getting a trusted service if you can, such as google or anyone with a good reputation, would be more trustworthy to users.